# Was Andy Garcia born with a Conjoined Twin?

Tags: medical-science, celebrities

Does Andy Garcia really have a scar on his shoulder from a childhood surgery to remove a half-formed twin? I've seen it around the net, for [example on NNDB](http://www.nndb.com/people/534/000024462/):

> Andy Garcia was born with a conjoined twin the size of a softball attached to his shoulder. It was surgically removed, and Garcia has no memory of it.